# Ruffus pipeline with internal inputs

Tags: python, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, pipeline, ruffus

I'd like to create a pipeline with the Ruffus package for Python and I am struggling with its simplest concepts. Two tasks should be executed one after the other. The second task depends on output of the first task. In Ruffus documentation everything is designed for import/export from/to external files. I'd like to handle internal data types like dictionaries.

The problem is that @follows doesn't take inputs and @transform doesn't take dicts. Am I missing something?

```
def task1():
    # generate dict
    properties = {'status': 'original'}
    return properties

@follows(task1)
def task2(properties):
    # update dict
    properties['status'] = 'updated'
    return properties
```

Eventually the pipeline should combine a set of functions in a class that update the class object on the go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only use the Ruffus decorators when there are input/output *files*. For example, if `task1` generates `file1.txt` and this is the input for `task2`, which generates `file2.txt` then you could write a pipeline as follows:

```
@originate('file1.txt')
def task1(output):
    with open(output,'w') as out_file:
        # write stuff to out_file

@follows(task1)
@transform(task1, suffix('1.txt'),'2.txt')
def task2(input_,output):
    with open(input_) as in_file, open(output,'w') as out_file:
        # read stuff from in_file and write stuff to out_file
```

If you just want to take a dictionary as an input, you don't need Ruffus, you can just order the code appropriately (as it will run sequentially) or call `task1` in `task2`:

```
def task1():
    properties = {'status': 'original'}
    return properties

def task2():
    properties = task1()
    properties['status'] = 'updated'
    return properties
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I wanted to construct a modular pipeline without the dependency directly in the tasks. This is why I wanted to abuse the Ruffus package for dictionaries. It seems that Ruffus is not meant for this kind of hack :)

Comment: @Damian When you call `pipeline_run` it checks the existence (and time stamp) of the files so I think your desired behavior is not possible with Ruffus